# Prime number sieve using ranges::view::ints

Tags: c++, primes, c++17

I wrote a simple prime number generator in C++17.  The function `generate_primes(max)` generates all prime numbers up to `max`.  I aimed for maximum portability.  Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>

namespace view = ranges::view;

using number_t = std::uint_fast32_t;
using numbers_t = std::set<number_t>;

numbers_t generate_primes(number_t max)
{
    if (max < 2)
        return {};

    numbers_t primes{view::ints(number_t(2), max)};
    for (number_t n = 2; n * n <= max; ++n) {
        if (primes.find(n) != primes.end()) {
            for (number_t m = 2; m <= max / n; ++m)
                primes.erase(n * m);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

I used the `ints` utility from the [Ranges library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) to populate `primes`.  `view::ints(number_t(2), max)` lazily generates all the integers of type `number_t` that is greater or equal to 2 and that is less than or equal to `max` in ascending order.  In C++20, the Ranges library is standardized.

Example usage:

```
void print(std::ostream& os, const numbers_t& nums)
{
    // convert to unsigned long so that it can be portability printed
    for (unsigned long n : nums)
        os << n << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print(std::cout, generate_primes(100));
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

Comment: @TobySpeight I only used `view::ints` a single time, does it deserve so much promotion? :D

Comment: Not really - I was just trying to find something different to give the question a unique title.  I don't mind if you change it again.  (I don't think the "unique title" rule works very well here on CR, unlike the other stacks...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may well be more efficient to compute `std::sqrt(max)` once upfront than to multiply `n * n` every time around the loop.

Removing an element by value from the set is O(log *n*), where *n* is the set size at the time.  This will likely make this method slower than writing to elements in a fixed-size storage (such as a `std::vector` that's never resized), and creating the return set from that.  Also, `find()` is much slower than vector lookup.

I think we can probably test `m * n <= max` instead of the more expensive `m <= max / n`, if we can arrange that the multiplication doesn't overflow.  It will be fine if `2 * n < std::numeric_limits<number_t>::max() - max`.  Also, no need to start at `2 * n` when removing - we can start at `n * n` instead, as all the lower multiples have already been removed due to their smaller factor(s).

And a tiny improvement to the test code - we can stream a single character `'\n'` to output rather than the string `"\n"`.

Comment: How to make sure that `std::sqrt(max)` is decently accurate?  I don't think a `uint_fast32_t` can be losslessly converted to `double` ...

Comment: That's a good question - you're right that there's only a lower bound on the size of `std::uint_fast32_t` and no upper bound.  My instinct would be to simply round up the result using `std::ceil`, but you if you're sufficiently paranoid, you could always advance to the next representable value after that.  Or, fall back to the `n * n` test using `||`, so the expensive version would only be evaluated the last time around the loop (or last two times if there's a rounding problem).  (cont...)

Comment: ... IOW, `auto const limit = static_cast<std::uint_fast32_t>(std::ceil(std::sqrt(max)));  for (...; n <= limit || n * n <= max; ...)`